# JS variable encapsulation

Tags: javascript

I am not sure if it's related to closure or it's related to JS call by assigning and hope someone could help clarify this.

The expected result below is to print **A, B, C** separately.

I guess the reason it's not working is that when the function added to array is executed, the **name** variable inside the function points to value **C** so the result is **C,C,C** not **A,B,C**

Then I tried to use IIFE to encapsulate(not sure if it's the right word) **name** variable and it works.

But what confuses me is that I thought the primitive variable should have passed value instead of reference? Or it is not the cause for this outcome and related to something else (maybe mysterious closure)?

**This is not working**

```js
let names = ["A", "B", "C"];
let targetPages = [];

function setName() {
  for (var name of names) {
    targetPages.push(function() {
      console.log(name);
    });
  };
};

setName();

for (var f in targetPages) {
  targetPages[f]();
}
```

**This is working.**

```js
let names = ["A", "B", "C"];
let targetPages = [];

function setTarget() {
    for(var name of names) {
        (function(n) {
            targetPages.push(function() {
                console.log(n);
            });    
        }(name));        
    };    
};

setTarget();

for(var f in targetPages) {
    targetPages[f]();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var):

> The **var statement** declares a function-scoped or globally-scoped variable, optionally initializing it to a value.

So loop and `if` conditional statements with their block scopes are not respected by `var`. Hence, making the first of your example display the last value of the variable `name`.

You can take the example below as a way to clarify how `var` statements work:

```js
for(var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  var j = 100;
}

console.log(i, j);
```

Since variables declared by `var` only respects function-scope and global-scope, then declarations within a block-scope is not respected as an isolated variable.

Your second example uses an [IIFE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE), which is technically calling the function immediately with the correct `name` argument. This coincides with how **mdn** explains how `var` statements work.

An alternative to using an `IIFE` is the usage of [const](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/const) and [let](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let), which respects block-scope.

I'll use your first example, and use `const` instead of `var`:

```js
let names = ["A", "B", "C"];
let targetPages = [];

function setName() {
  for (const name of names) {
    targetPages.push(function() {
      console.log(name);
    });
  };
};

setName();

for (const f in targetPages) {
  targetPages[f]();
}
```

Conclusion:

Using `const` and `let` let's you avoid these problems in development. But if you're supporting older browser, e.g. IE11, which does not support these statements, then you may use [babel](https://babeljs.io/) to transpile or compile your code to work with such older browsers.

Comment: Thanks you for pointing out why IIFE works :)

Answer (score 2):

The thing that is causing this is *variable hoisting*. In JS, defining a variable with `var` makes that variable *function-scope*, and the declaration of that variable is *hoisted* to the top of the block.

Let's take your first code example of the function `setName`. Due to variable hoisting, your code is identical to this:

```js
function setName() {
  var name; // hoisted declaration
  for (let i = 0; i < names.length; i++) {
    name = names[i]; // initialization
    targetPages.push(function() {
      console.log(name);
    });
  };
  // `name` has a final value of "C" after the for loop
};
```

What this means is that when you call `setName()`, `targetPages` gets three functions that all reference the `name` variable defined in `setName`. However, note that at the end of the for loop inside `setName`, `name` is set to `"C"`. Therefore, if you try to call any of the `targetPages[f]` functions, then you will print out the *new* value of `name` - since it changed after the function declaration.

Similarly, the following code prints `4`:

```js
let x = 3;
function f() {
    console.log(x);
}
x = 4;
f();
```

This can be solved using `let`, which doesn't suffer from variable hoisting:

```js
function setName() {
  //   vvv
  for (let name of names) {
    targetPages.push(function() {
      console.log(name);
    });
  };
};
```

[See MDN's "Creating closures in loops: a common mistake" for more information.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures#creating_closures_in_loops_a_common_mistake)

Comment: Ah I totally looked into the wrong direction. Thanks for the clarification